# How to order rows except one row in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have string field `NAME` and some rows.
How I can ORDER these rows by `NAME` with DESC direction, but except one value with ID = 3?

So I need to add one value to the end:

```
A
B
C

KU-KU
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just put the logic in the `order by`:

```
order by (id = 3) desc, name
```

MySQL treats a boolean expression as a number in a numeric context, with true being 1 and false being 0.  Hence the `desc` after the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Create a virtual column that handles the sort rule you require, such as this fairly trivial example:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN id = 3 THEN "~~~~~~~~~" ELSE name END AS sortfield,
       name, ...
  FROM ...
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Comment: No, was a more elegant solution with ORDER BY params

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY id != 3 DESC, name ASC

That is, you can not do what you said. You can not ORDER everything BY some idea, except one of those things. You **can** ORDER BY **two criteria**, first your crazy criterion (for which, everything besides your freaky value is the same), and then by something that is different for every row.